# SetForce with ODE Engine: error in documentation?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

I've written a ModelPlugin which calls physics::Joint::SetForce(int, double) on a revolute joint using the ODE physics engine. According to the documentation [Gazebo API doc](http://osrf-distributions.s3.amazonaws.com/gazebo/api/dev/classgazebo_1_1physics_1_1Joint.html#a1eb00145de3a61aaa0ee7506a6ab44c2) this should only work for SimBody and DART engine (I'm using gazebo 4.1).
However, it works as expected.

My question is: can I safely use this with ODE, i.e. it's only an error in the documentation, or do I have to expect this behaviour will break in some update?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/7894/setforce-with-ode-engine:-error-in-documentation?/) by [Moritz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1049/moritz/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 15 on 2015-01-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The `SetForce` method is implemented for all the physics engines, check for example the [ODE implementation](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/c032cdc3eb010aa3f3e53613606ccf2c3b68d8d7/gazebo/physics/ode/ODEJoint.cc?at=default#cl-1098) and the [Bullet implementation](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/c032cdc3eb010aa3f3e53613606ccf2c3b68d8d7/gazebo/physics/bullet/BulletJoint.cc?at=default#cl-431).

However a known issue is that the `SetForce` documentation is incomplete, see the related issue in the Gazebo Bug-tracker: https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/878/joint-setforce-documentation-incomplete . If you plan to use this function, I suggest you vote for this issue.

---

Originally posted by [silvio.traversaro](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/455/silvio.traversaro/) with karma: 200 on 2015-01-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2